Calling solana.getParsedProgramAccounts method on a Token-2022 returns an empty array
When calling the below method getParsedProgramAccounts with the correct Token Program ID and a Token Address associated with that Token Program ID, I am returned an array of the token holders.  However, when calling the below method getParsedProgramAccounts with the correct Token-2022 Program ID and a Token-2022 Address, the call returns an empty array.
But, the Token-2022 addresses I pass does actually have holders.
What could be the issue here? Am I passing the incorrect parameters to the method for Token-2022 addresses? Thanks
await solana.getParsedProgramAccounts(accountInfo?.owner as PublicKey, {
        commitment: 'confirmed',
        filters: [
          {
            dataSize: 165,
          },
          {
            memcmp: {
              offset: 0,
              bytes: tokenAddress,
            },
          },
        ],
      }), 


Does the token use extensions? the account size may be different. What is the token you're trying to fetch?

Since token accounts can have different sizes due to various extensions, you should remove the dataSize filter to get the accounts, so instead, do:
await solana.getParsedProgramAccounts(accountInfo?.owner as PublicKey, {
        commitment: 'confirmed',
        filters: [
          {
            memcmp: {
              offset: 0,
              bytes: tokenAddress,
            },
          },
        ],
      }), 

